# How to check elasticsearch searchresponse is success or failure for a given search

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I am querying elasticsearch with the below query

```
SearchResponse searchResponse = getElasticSearchClient() 
                            .prepareSearch(indexNameStr).setTypes(typeNameStr) 
                            .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH) 
                            .setQuery(queryStrr).setSize(size) 
                            .setFrom(start).addSort(fieldSortBuilder) 
                            .execute().actionGet();
```

I wanted to check if the search is success or failure. Catch exception If there are any during search.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , even if a shard fails for a particular search , the search request will still go through. Only way to check if all shards were successful would be to check the response and see if there is any shard failures marked.

```
if(searchResponse.getShardFailures().length > 0){
    System.out.println("Failed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for the client that you are using.  In the C# client the IResponse object returned has an "IsValid" property that tells you if the response was successful or not.

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/fac2eb8e3715e7ad216e81ddbef48f45e56654d9/docs/contents/nest/handling-responses.markdown

Comment: I am using java transport client